# Extract a value from MATLAB codistributed array

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I am attempting to build a distributed array of handle class objects in MATLAB and I would like to extract a specific handle from this vector for use on the command line. Given the code below, I would like the following to execute. I am running this on with two labs (matlabpool 2). The getValue function is what I need assistance with, thanks...

```
vec = buildArray; 
h = getValue(vec,6);
h.id
```

**ClassA.m**:
A class that I would like to distribute in parallel.

```
classdef ClassA < handle
    properties
        id;
    end

    methods
       function obj = ClassA(id)
        obj.id = id;
       end
    end   
end
```

**buildArray.m**:
A function to build codistributed array from local instances of ClassA.

```
function vec = buildArray
X(:,1) = 1:10;              % create ids
gsize = size(X);            % the global size
X = distributed(X);         % distribute the ids

spmd    
    x = getLocalPart(X);       % extract the local ids
    local = cell(length(x),1); % create local storage for handles

    % Create the class instances
    for i = 1:length(x);     
        local{i} = ClassA(x(i));    
    end

    % Build the codistributed array of handles
    codist = codistributor1d(codistributor1d.unsetDimension, ...
    codistributor1d.unsetPartition, gsize);
    vec = codistributed.build(local,codist);
end
```

**getValue.m**:
*This is the function that I need help with*, currently it just displays what lab that contains the class with the specified id. I would like for it to return the handle so it may be used from the command line. How is this done?

```
function h = getValue(vec, id)
h = []; % just so it will not throw an error
spmd
 local = getLocalPart(vec);
 for i = 1:length(local);
    if local{i}.id == id;
        % Export h here
        disp(['ID ', num2str(id), ' is on lab ', num2str(labindex)]);
        break;
    end
 end 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get my problem working using this for getValue.m, is there a better way?

```
function h = getValue(vec, id)

spmd  
local = getLocalPart(vec);
idx = [];
for i = 1:length(local);
    if local{i}.id == id;
        idx = i;
        break;
    end
end 

codist = codistributor1d(codistributor1d.unsetDimension, ...
    codistributor1d.unsetPartition, [numlabs,1]);
IDX = codistributed.build(idx, codist); 
end

c = gather(vec(IDX));
h = c{1};
```